# 2 methods in Web Service, one works, one returns with 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, sharepoint-2010

I have two methods in an svc web service, one takes no arguments and returns all Active Directory users. This one works. I have another method that receives a user ID and returns all of the groups they are a member of. This one fails with "400 (bad request)" on our Beta site, but works properly with identical code and calling methods on my local development box. I have used fiddler to ensure that the JSON being sent to the web service is correct in both instances. Both environments are SharePoint.

I have checked the authentication providers for the sites both in beta and my dev environment and they are identical.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing AJAX, you will not get an Internal Server Error 500 message. If you're sure of your inputs (no ampersand in parameters, etc) and other methods are not yielding errors, it is likely your code is crashing in the method returning 400 (Bad Request).

It turns out that there was a security issue on the Beta server that would not return a user principal unless specifying the Super User able to see domain accounts, its domain and password. There was no check for null on the user principal object before attempting to use its properties, and it was throwing an Internal Server error.

Comment: Also, no 500 error was logged, but the 400 was in IIS logs. Don't assume the error code is accurately depicting what is happening for 400 errors.